# The value 'xx/xx/xxxx' is not valid for "y" - Jquery Datepicker DateTime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery datepicker to pick the date in my MVC application and I'm using the `dd/MM/yyy` format.

When I submit the form I get this error:

`The value '24/05/2017' is not valid for Datum vertrek`.

This is my script in my View:

```
$("#date").datepicker(
    {
        minDate: '0',
        maxDate: '14D',
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
    });
```

This is the property in my ViewModel:

`[Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht")]
 [Display(Name = "Datum vertrek")]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime? DepartureDate { get; set; }`

However I never had this error when I was running the application offline. I just published the application and suddenly I started getting this error.

Comment: Your datepicker format and DisplayFormat are different

Comment: If I use dd/MM/yy in javascript the name of the month is displayed instead of the number of the month

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov the dd/MM/yyyy format is in the C# code and matches JavaScript's dd/mm/yy format

Comment: This feels like it's the model binding that is not co-operating and is not parsing the date correctly. What happens if you try 12/05/2017? does it work? does it get interpreted as 5th December 2017?

Comment: Just realised this is an old question. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

instead of `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`

Comment: From the jQuery Datepicker docs - > **y - year (two digit)** and **yy - year (four digit)**